# English dictionary based word count in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do some text analysis and I was wondering if there is any tool or package that recognize different forms of English words (eg. singular, plural, past, present, etc) and get the word counts.

In this string vector `myvec <- c("fired", "fires", "firing", "fired", "hospitals", "Hospitals", "hospital", "hospitalization", "Hospitalized")`, I want to get the count for word `Fire` = 4 and word `Hospital` = 5.

Comment: @r2evans That would give 
`fired     fires    firing  hospital hospitals Hospitals 
        2         1         1         1         1         1 `

Comment: MAPK, I deleted it, apparently not quickly enough :-). Have you tried the [`NLP`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLP/index.html) package? Its revdeps might give clue to further advances in it if the package itself is insufficient.

Answer (score 3):

check out the [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing#Rule-based_vs._statistical_NLP) technique.

> Stemming - The process of reducing inflected (or sometimes derived)
>   words to their root form. (e.g. "close" will be the root for "closed",
>   "closing", "close", "closer" etc).

```
install.packages("tm")
library(tm)

mydf <- data.frame(doc_id = seq(1:9), 
                    text = c("fired", "fires", "firing", "fired", "hospitals", "Hospitals", "hospital", "hospitalization", "Hospitalized"), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mycorpus <- SimpleCorpus(DataframeSource(mydf))

mytmmap <- tm_map(mycorpus, stemDocument, language = "english")  

inspect(mycorpus)

inspect(mytmmap)

# <<SimpleCorpus>>
# Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0
# Content:  documents: 9
#
#     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9 
#  fire   fire   fire   fire hospit Hospit hospit hospit Hospit
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be `stringdist`, but this would work

```
f1 <- function(patVec, vec, nameVec) {
       out <- colSums(sapply(patVec, agrepl, x = vec,
             max.distance = 0.1, ignore.case = TRUE))
       names(out) <- nameVec
       out
    }
        
o1 <-  f1(c("fire", "hospital"), myvec, c("Fire", "Hospital"))
          
o1
#    Fire Hospital 
#       4        3
```

For second vector

```
o1 <- f1(c("fire", "hospital"), myvec2, c("Fire", "Hospital"))
o1
#    Fire Hospital 
#      4        5
```

---

Or use `soundex`

```
library(phonics)
o2 <- table(substr(soundex(myvec), 1, 2))
names(o2) <- c("Fire", "Hospital")
o2
#   Fire Hospital 
#      4        3
```

For the second vector

```
o2 <- table(substr(soundex(myvec2), 1, 2))
names(o2) <- c("Fire", "Hospital")
o2
#    Fire Hospital 
#       4        5
```

All the methods give the expected output in the OP's post

#### data

```
myvec <- c("fired", "fires", "firing", "fired", "hospitals", "Hospitals", "hospital")
myvec2 <- c("fired", "fires", "firing", "fired", "hospitals", "Hospitals", "hospital", "hospitalization", "Hospitalized")
```

Comment: It would not work for different types of words. Only (`e|i`)

Comment: @MAPK Based on your examples showed, the `agrep` (modified) and the `soundex` works.  If you have a new vector, please update your post.  Without that, the downvote seems unfair

Answer (score 0):

A stemming example using the `Quanteda` library. https://quanteda.io/

```
install.packages("quanteda")

library(quanteda)

mytext = c("fired", "fires", "firing", "fired", "hospitals", "Hospitals", "hospital", "hospitalization", "Hospitalized")

mytoks <- tokens(mytext)

toks_stem <- tokens_wordstem(mytoks, "english")
# tokens from 9 documents.
#[1] "fire",  "fire", "fire", "fire", "hospit", "Hospit", "hospit", "hospit", "Hospit"
```

Quanteda Cheatsheet - https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/quanteda.pdf